# creating sqlite database with google gears. widget sdk

Tags: javascript, blackberry, google-gears

I have a JavaScript function named "openDatabase()" that starts with:

```
function openDatabase() {
   try {
       _db = google.gears.factory.create('beta.database');
      ...//more code
  }
  catch(err) {
     alert(err.name + " " + err.message);
  }
```

i have created my sqlite database with success running on the simulators for the Bold 9700 and Storm 2 9550.  When i deploy this same app to a real device(the new torch), an exception is caught with `err.name` "ReferenceError" and `err.message` "Can't find variable: google"

why doesn't it know what google is? i am importing these javascript files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/html5_init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/gears.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like google gears is not installed - your application [should check this](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/design.html#detecting)